# ESP32 Read stat from MCP73831

Tags: battery-charging, esp32

I'm trying to detect if the charger(MCP73831) is Charging or Complete
I found a circuit through google images but not to sure of it.
The MCU is a ESP32-C3, the ADC pin is being used to connect to the stat (GPIO8/BATTSTAT)
Does this look correct?[image]